# Regex for the following format in html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, regex

I want regex/html pattern for the following format in html to validate fields.[image]

Please go through above image to see format and the format will be continued for the hours and days of week etc. additional work :-> it should not allow other characters except the allowed characters. if this not possible also ok, but at least pattern is required.

i have tried this, its allowing the value which is more than 59(ex:->60,73 etc). according to condition it should not allow and the pattern which i used is `pattern="(^[0-9\d\-/*,\s]+$)"`.

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <input matInput placeholder="Enter seconds" formControlName="seconds" pattern="(^[0-9\d\-/*,\s]+$)">
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('seconds')?.invalid"> Enter Proper Value</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field
```

And here input should allow only special characters and value up to 59 which you can see in image, if we enter value which is more than 59(ex:->60 or 70) it should not accept and if we enter other special characters which is not mentioned in image, it should not allow(alphabets are not allowed a-z).

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Post CODE, nut just pictures.

Comment: what code you are expecting here? am i asking logic kind of things here to write code, its just pattern and whatever i used its there cant u see? i am asking for help, even i have searched everything in stack overflow itself. did not get proper solution. before down voting you should check properly @mplungjan

Comment: Do not assume the comments are by the downvotes. Add a [mcve] with your rendered HTML, the pattern in the pattern attribute and how to recreate your issue.

Comment: I thought u down voted anyways thanks if you know the answer for allowed characters and allowed values which is in image. i have used above pattern but its not working. if you know please help me.

Comment: Please help us help you by answering my request

Comment: I hope this much info is enough to answer.

Comment: A number from `0` tp `59` and any of the mentioned special chars? Try `pattern="[-/*,\s]*(?:[06-9]|[1-5]\d?))[-/*,\s]*"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 different requirements here.

First requirement is to disallow wrong characters, you can achieve that as described in this article

https://medium.com/@MelkorNemesis/prevent-unwanted-characters-in-input-f2967132decb

The other part is the none acceptance of e.g. 73 minutes. That, for all elements (minutes, seconds, days etc) make a regular expression utterly complex and I honestly think you shouldn't try that. Instead of disallowing the input 73 minutes you should simply create a Validator on your form, which parses the datetime string from the input and shows the validation error when the datetime can't be parsed.

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to validate this with a single regex because you want to validate against a list of valid chars, and validate a number range. Here is a solution with three regexes:

```js
[
  '12',
  '-1,2*',
  'x12',
  '60',
  '-6,0*'
].forEach(function(str) {
  console.log(str + '  ==> ' + validateSeconds(str));
});

function validateSeconds(str) {
  var validRegex = /^[0-9,\-\*/]*$/;
  var numberRegex = /[^0-9]/g;
  var rangeRegex = /^([0-9]|[1-5][0-9])$/;
  if(validRegex.test(str)) {
    return rangeRegex.test(str.replace(numberRegex, ''));
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
12  ==> true
-1,2*  ==> true
x12  ==> false
60  ==> false
-6,0*  ==> false
```

Explanation of the `validateSeconds()` function:

1. `validRegex = /^[0-9,\-\*/]*$/` - we first make sure that only valid characters are present, so we test against this regex
2. `numberRegex = /[^0-9]/g` - delete all non-digits after valid characters test
3. `rangeRegex = /^([0-9]|[1-5][0-9])$/` - now we can check the range; it is either a single digit `[0-9]`, or a two digit number where the first digit is `[1-5]` and the second digit is `[0-9]`